# 2 Ubuntu 10.04 64Bit servers Guest in VMware Workstation 7.1.3 with Windows 7 64Bit Host randomly loose conenction

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vmware, ftp, connection

OK... heres my setup... On a private server, Per friends request I have two separate virtual machines, both ubuntu 10.04 64bit linux servers. With a Windows 7 64bit host, Connected directly to a router. 

lets refer to the systems by their host names.

WebServer; (Ubuntu 10.04 Server x64, setup with SSH, LAMP, and PROFTPd)

```
    - Network adapter: VMware NAT translation;
    - IP: Static
    - Address: 192.168.2.5
    - Netmask: 255.255.255.0
    - Network: 192.168.2.0
    - Broadcast: 192.168.2.255
    - Gateway: 182.168.2.1
- Resolve.conf: Nameserver 192.168.2.1<br/>
- IPv6: Disabled
```

Ports forwarded to this machine:

```
- HTTP Port: 80<br/>
- SSH Port: 22<br/>
- FTP: 21<br/>
```

IRCServer; (Ubuntu 10.04 Server x64, setup with SSH, LAMP, and UnrealIRCd \w anope):

```
    - Network adapter: VMware NAT translation;<br/>
    - IP: Static<br/>
    - Address: 192.168.2.8<br/>
    - Netmask: 255.255.255.0<br/>
    - Network: 192.168.2.0<br/>
    - Broadcast: 192.168.2.255<br/>
    - Gateway: 182.168.2.1<br/>
- Resolve.conf: Nameserver 192.168.2.1<br/>
- IPv6: Enabled (disabled on WebServer because I was getting flooded with no 
IPv6 Routers Present errors along with the disconnection)
```

Ports forwarded to this machine:
    - SSH Port: 2222
    - UnrealIRCD: 6667

Desktop:

```
- Windows 7 x64<br/>
- 8GB Ram<br/>
- 2.2GHz Phenom 9550 Quad-Core<br/>
- Marvell Yukon 88E8071 PCI-E Ethernet Controller<br/>
```

My problem is that randomly, One of the servers would loose all connection. (hardly ever happens to IRCServer, Not sure what causes it).
WebServer will loose all connection often when I try to login with FTP, (FileZilla from Desktop, connecting to 192.168.2.1).
No additions to dmesg, ifconfig eth0 says its still up, and its ip is 192.168.2.5 (.8 for IRCServer), and if I $host google.com it fails with the error:

`;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

*Note: I thought it useful to add that, to fix this, all I have to do is sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart*

Am I missing somthing here? I am normally quite good with this kind stuff, Have been using Ubuntu for 4+ years. And Google even longer, I have a feeling its right in front of me, but I don't see it.

*Another note: Nothing in the syslog, And its not the adapter as its the same software adapter for both systems, and when WebServer goes down, IRCServer remains connected*

Comment: You shouldn't really cross-post exactly the same question to multiple sites like this. http://serverfault.com/questions/276523/2-ubuntu-10-04-64bit-servers-guest-in-vmware-workstation-7-1-3-with-windows-7-64b